# Removing objects from a vector

Tags: c++, object, vector

I have stored objects in a vector, where each object has a staff number property. If a user wants to delete an object from the vector, the user can enter the staff number so that the specific object will get deleted from the vector.

```
void Administrator::deleteMember()
{
    string staffNumber;
    FileHandler<Administrator> adminTObj;
    cout<<"Enter Staff Number of the Member to Delete"<<endl;
    cin>>staffNumber;

    if(staffNumber.find("Ad"))
    {
        vector<Administrator> myVec=adminTObj.getVectorAdministrator();
        for(Administrator iter:myVec)
        {
            if(iter.getStaffNumber()==staffNumber)  //checks if the staff number matches an object's staff number 
            {
                // If it matches it should delete the record (Need to implement)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I delete the object from the vector?

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector for everything you can do on a vector. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm for things you can do to anything you can describe with an iterator sequence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a single element, you can use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to get an iterator to the element, and [`std::vector::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) to remove it.

```
auto it = std::find_if(myVec.begin(), 
                       myVec.end(),
                       [staffNumber](const Administrator& a)
                       { return a.getStaffNumber() == staffNumber; });

myVec.erase(it);
```

If you want to remove all elements satisfying a criterion, use [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) and `std::vector::erase` (the [*erase-remove idiom*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom)).

```
auto it = std::remove_if(myVec.begin(), 
                         myVec.end(),
                         [staffNumber](const Administrator& a)
                         { return a.getStaffNumber() == staffNumber; });

myVec.erase(it, myVec.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the member function `vector::erase()`, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `erase` method, which is documented [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/); however you should break the loop immediateley afterwards, as the call of `erase` would perhaps invalidate the iterator.

Comment: erase helpfully returns a valid iterator although I forget if it is to the previous or next element.

Comment: @ZanLynx It is the next element, as documented here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/

Answer (score 0):

This is how to erase a specific item from the vector by its index id.

```
int at;
vector<Administrator> myVec=adminTObj.getVectorAdministrator();
at = indexToErase;
myVec.erase(myVec.begin()+at)
```